# Highcharts - Column Chart: Compare corresponding values to change color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to set up a fixed placement column set where the corresponding series data is compared and if one piece is trending below the baseline, that color will change.

So for example, on the default fixed placement column set seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/a8Dg2/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Seattle HQ',
            'San Francisco',
            'Tokyo'
        ]
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Employees'
        }
    },{
        title: {
            text: 'Profit (millions)'
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    legend: {
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            grouping: false,
            shadow: false,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Employees',
        color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
        data: [150, 73, 20],
        pointPadding: 0.3,
        pointPlacement: -0.2
    }, {
        name: 'Employees Optimized',
        color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
        data: [140, 90, 40],
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: -0.2
    },{
        name: 'Profit',
        color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
        data: [183.6, 178.8, 198.5],
        tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$',
            valueSuffix: ' M'
        },
        pointPadding: .3,
        pointPlacement: 0.2,
        yAxis: 1
    },{
        name: 'Profit Optimized',
        color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
        data: [203.6, 198.8, 208.5],
        tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$',
            valueSuffix: ' M'
        },
        pointPadding: .4,
        pointPlacement: 0.2,
        yAxis: 1
    }]
});
```

});

In Seattle HQ, since Employees Optimized is trending below the Employees column, I would like to have the color of Employees Optimized change to green dynamically based on the values between the corresponding data between the two series.

Essentially and If x < y, color:green.

Thanks so much for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices. You can either pre-process your data and append a color property in your `data` array such that it looks like:

```
{
            name: 'Employees Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
            data: [{y: 140, color: 'green'}, 90, 40],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }
```

Or you can dynamically assign the color using the [`chart.events.load`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) function. In this function you can loop over your series data points (assuming you are looking at 'Employees Optimized' that is `series[1]`). Then compare each point to the same indexed point in `series[0]` ('Employees'). Then if your conditions are met update the point's color. Here is an exceptionally verbose method to do this:

```
    events: {
        load: function (event) {
            var theSeries = this.series[1];
            var theCompSeries = this.series[0];
            var theData = theSeries.data;
            var theCompData = theCompSeries.data;

            for (var i = 0; i < theData.length; i++) {
                var theDataPoint = theData[i].y
                var theCompDataPoint = theCompData[i].y;
                if (theData[i].y < theCompData[i].y) {
                    console.log(theSeries);
                    theSeries.points[i].update({
                        color: 'green'
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Live **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WD2fd/)**.

Comment: As I said, very verbose ;).